# Differentiation of $f(t) = 5t^2-5t$ and $p(t) = 5t(t-1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As you can see in the title, $f(t)$ and $p(t)$ are basically the same equation. However, I don't understand why differentiation of $f(t) = 5t^2-5t$ and $p(t) = 5t(t-1)$ is different. Without factoring, I use the difference rule for $(5t^2-5t)$ and product rule for $5t(t-1)$ and I am keep getting $f'(t) = 10t-5$ and $p'(t) =  5t-5$

Am I missing something?

difference rule $f'(t)-q'(t)$

product rule $f(t)q'(t)+q(t)f'(t)$

Comment: $p'(t) = 5[(1)(t-1) + t(1)] = 5(2 t - 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$p'(t)=(5t)'(t-1)+5t(t-1)'=5(t-1)+5t=10t-5=f'(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**
$$p'(t)=\frac{\text{d}(5t)}{\text{d}t}(t-1)+\frac{\text{d}(t-1)}{\text{d}t}(5t)$$

$$=5(t-1)+5t=10t-5=f'(t)$$

---

> and product rule for $5t(t−1)5t(t−1)$ and I am keep getting $f′(t)=10t−5f′(t)=10t−5$ and '$$p′(t)=5t−5$$'
>
> You did the calculation wrong